# php ical Google import issue

Tags: php, datetime, calendar, timezone, icalendar

I am facing issue with he even time stamp. Below is an iCal import for an Event. I am importing a event for 6th and 7th of Oct so

End: **DTEND:20141007T235900Z**

Start: **DTSTART:20141006T000000Z**

As per my Time the even should be from 06-Oct-2014 00:00:00 to 07-Oct-2014 23:59:00 But After I import the iCal Google shown the event till 8th-Oct-2014

> Mon, October 6, 5:30am – Wed, October 8, 5:29am

[image]

**I see a 5.30 Hours Additional Time in the Events how can I control this to actual time. As I am from India the time stamp will be 5.30+ compare to international timings? Is that some thing I need to do fro that?**

**How can I set time zone?**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20141007T235900Z
UID:3e3c0ac9c32a20e57791f450417db001
DTSTAMP:20130716T055817Z
URL;VALUE=URI:http://mohawkaustin.com/events/
DESCRIPTION:TEST GOOGLE
SUMMARY:TEST GOOGLE
DTSTART:20141006T000000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set timezone in google, https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37064?hl=en
Google will always convert to the users timezone.

If you want a floating timezone (ie will always be that time no matter the timezone) , leave the Z off. Z means UTC timezone.

If you want to set the timezone in th eics file (eg to india) then do something like

DTSTART;TZID=”America/New_York”:20080807T090000
except of course for india.